# How to create future unit?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have this code:

```
def updateDocSetting(data: Seq[ModelDocumentSetting])=  {

    for (a <- data){    
       DocumentSettingTable
         .filter(_.doc_proc_list_id === a.doc_proc_list_id)
         .map(doc => (doc.is_mandatory,doc.is_display,doc.is_deleted))
         .update(a.is_mandatory,a.is_display,a.is_deleted)
    }

}
```

I have a problem to get the future slick result on my service code
this is my service code

```
def updateDocSetting(data: List[ModelDocumentSetting]): Future[Unit] = {
   db.run(DalDocumentSetting.updateDocSetting(data))
}
```

> error:type mismatch; found : Unit required:
>   slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Unit,slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the sequence of `DBIOAction`s to a single `DBIOAction` using `DBIO.sequence`.

Use `yield` to get the sequence of DBIO actions:

```
  for (a <- data) yield {    
     DocumentSettingTable
       .filter(_.doc_proc_list_id === a.doc_proc_list_id)
       .map(doc => (doc.is_mandatory,doc.is_display,doc.is_deleted))
       .update(a.is_mandatory,a.is_display,a.is_deleted)
   }
```

And then:

```
db.run(DBIO.sequence(DalDocumentSetting.updateDocSetting(data)))
```